# Error in setInterval function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a javascript and php quiz. The code is simple: it uses ajax request to check the answer if any of the option button is clicked. It is working fine but after an user clicks any of the given option I want the question to be changed automatically making a new ajax request after 2 seconds. So I used SetInterval function with load function to load the new question. Now the main problen is here:
When I click any of the option button the next question appears and goes and again appears. The question keeps jittering as if it is an animation error. So is wrong in the below code thats making this happen?

**Code:**(*CSS is removed*)

*index.php*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
    <title>Quiz</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <style type="text/css">

    </style>
    <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function loadqn() {
            $('.optioncont').load('loadit.php?id=1');
        }

        function checkans(qid, optn) {

            $(".optioncont").css("opacity", "0.5");
            var id = qid + 1;
            alert(id);
            setInterval(function () { $('.optioncont').load('loadit.php?id=' + id); }, 2000);

            $.ajax({
                url: 'quiz.php',
                method: 'POST',
                data: {
                    qnid: qid,
                    ans: optn
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data == 'C') {
                        $(".resultN").hide();
                        $(".resultY").show();
                        setInterval(function () { $(".resultY").hide(); }, 3000);
                    } else {
                        $(".resultY").hide();
                        $(".resultN").show();
                        setInterval(function () { $(".resultN").hide(); }, 3000);
                    }
                }
            });
        }


        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#play").click(function () {
                alert('id');
                loadqn();
            });
        });

    </script>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="qncont">
        <button id="play">Play</button>
        <center>
            <div class="optioncont">
            </div>
            <div class="resultY">
                <div class="congrats">Correct Answer</div>
            </div>
            <div class="resultN">
                <div class="congrats">Wrong Answer</div>
            </div>


    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

*loadit.php*

```
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'bibek');
if (!$conn) {
    die("Database connection Failed" . mysqli_error($conn));
}
$select_db = mysqli_select_db($conn, 'test');
if (!$select_db) {
    die("Database selection falied" . mysqli_error($conn));
}

if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
    $qid = $_GET['id'];

    $query = mysqli_query($conn, "select* from `quiz` where id='$qid'");

    $row      = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
    $question = $row['question'];
    $option1  = $row['option1'];
    $option2  = $row['option2'];
    $option3  = $row['option3'];
    $option4  = $row['option4'];

    echo "<div class='question'>$question</div>";
    echo "<div class='option_block'><a href='#' class='option' onClick='checkans(" . $qid . ",1)'>$option1</a></div>";
    echo "<div class='option_block'><a href='#' class='option' onClick='checkans(" . $qid . ",2)'>$option2</a></div>";
    echo "<div class='option_block'><a href='#' class='option' onClick='checkans(" . $qid . ",3)'>$option3</a></div>";
    echo "<div class='option_block'><a class='option' href='#' onClick='checkans(" . $qid . ",4)'>$option4</a></div>";
} else {
    echo "error";
}
?>
```

Comment: setInterval repeats the function every `x` seconds, maybe you're talking about setTimeout?

Comment: It seems like you want to use `setTimeout` not `setInterval`

Comment: setTimeout(function, milliseconds)
Executes a function, after waiting a specified number of milliseconds.
setInterval(function, milliseconds)
Same as setTimeout(), but repeats the execution of the function continuously.

Comment: The next question appears after 2 seconds disappears shortly appears again and disappears again...this continous. Should I use setTimeout() ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @sjeiti wrote you should use `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval`.

The reason for you so called jittering is because the code continues with withe the `ajax-call` until the 2 seconds has pasted. So you should set your `ajax-call` inside your first `Timeout-function`

```
    function checkans(qid, optn) {

        $(".optioncont").css("opacity", "0.5");
        var id = qid + 1;
        alert(id);

        //THE CODE WON'T WAIT FOR THIS TO COMPLETE 
        setInterval(function () { $('.optioncont').load('loadit.php?id=' + id); }, 2000);

        //IT WILL JUMP TO THIS PART WHILE IT'S WAITING FOR THE TIMEOUT
        $.ajax({
            url: 'quiz.php',
            method: 'POST',
            data: {
                qnid: qid,
                ans: optn
            },
            success: function (data) {
                if (data == 'C') {
                    $(".resultN").hide();
                    $(".resultY").show();
                    setInterval(function () { $(".resultY").hide(); }, 3000);
                } else {
                    $(".resultY").hide();
                    $(".resultN").show();
                    setInterval(function () { $(".resultN").hide(); }, 3000);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Can you please explain in detail ? I used setTimeout instead of setInterval but an error occured.

Comment: Oh sorry! Actually the error was caused by another piece of code. It worked and thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

SetInterval will call your function repeatedly with an interval of x milliseconds.
You should use [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/ro/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout) or better [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/API/Window/requestAnimationFrame).

Note that you can cancel any `setInterval` or `setTimeout` with the `clearInterval` and `clearTimeOut` respectively.